# Sending parameters via the transaction Object

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, contract-invocation

This works just fine:

```
myContractObject.doSomething(i, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
     doSomethingElse(result)
    }
})
```

However, this doesn't:

```
  const params = myContractObject.doSomething.getData(i)
  const transactionObject = {from: account, data: params}
  myContractObject.doSomething(transactionObject, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
     doSomethingElse(result)
    }
  })
```

Here's what `params` looks like: `0xd1656c170000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

And here's what transactionObject looks like: `Object { from: "0x518f5defef41e5b9baed8c9fabc392dd5…", data: "0xd1656c170000000000000000000000000…" }`

Here's the relevant section of the `ABI` of the contract:

```
{
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "_index",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "doSomething",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "payable": false,
  "type": "function"
}
```

Am I misunderstanding the `transactionObject`? The `data:` section of `sendTransaction` is for specifying parameters to the contract method call, right?

I'm trying to set up a transaction handler function for a dApp I'm developing. That function needs to take a variable number of parameters; hence, my attempt at setting up the parameters in a `transactionObject`. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what the `data` key of a `transactionObject` is for, but it seems it isn't for sending parameters to method calls. So I've ended up solving my issue this way:

```
    _funcCallChecker(_func, _cb ) {
        if ( (typeof _func === 'function') || (typeof _cb === 'function') ) {
          return true
        } else {
          return false
        }   
    }

  _funcCallParamsChecker(_func, _params, _cb ) {
    if ( (typeof _func === 'function') || (typeof _cb === 'function') || (Array.isArray(_params)) ) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }   
  }

  _call (_caller, _func, _cb ) {
    if ( this._funcCallChecker(_func, _cb) ) {
      _func( function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          _cb(_caller, result)
        }
      })
    }   
}

  _call1Params (_caller, _func, _params, _cb ) {
    if ( this._funcCallParamsChecker(_func, _params, _cb ) ) {
      _func(_params[0], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          _cb(_caller, result)
        }
      })
    }  
 }

  _call2Params (_caller, _func, _params, _cb ) {
    if ( this._funcCallParamsChecker(_func, _params, _cb ) ) {
      _func(_params[0], _params[1], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          _cb(_caller, result)
        }
      })
    }  
 }

  _call3Params (_caller, _func, _params, _cb ) {
    if ( this._funcCallParamsChecker(_func, _params, _cb ) ) {
      _func(_params[0], _params[1], _params[2], _params[3], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          _cb(_caller, result)
        }
      })
    }  
 }

  _call4Params (_caller, _func, _params, _cb ) {
    if ( this._funcCallParamsChecker(_func, _params, _cb ) ) {
      _func(_params[0], _params[1], _params[2], _params[3], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          _cb(_caller, result)
        }
      })
    }   
  }

  _call5Params (_caller, _func, _params, _cb ) {
    if ( this._funcCallParamsChecker(_func, _params, _cb ) ) {
      _func(_params[0], _params[1], _params[2], _params[3], _params[4], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          _cb(_caller, result)
        }
      })
    }   
 }

  _call6Params (_caller, _func, _params, _cb ) {
    if ( this._funcCallParamsChecker(_func, _params, _cb ) ) {
      _func(_params[0], _params[1], _params[2], _params[3], _params[4], _params[5], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          _cb(_caller, result)
        }
      })
    }  
 }


  callHandler (_caller, _func, _cb ) {
    this._call(_caller, _func, _cb)   
 }

  callParamHandler (_caller, _func, _params, _cb ) {
    switch(_params.length) {
      case 1:
          this._call1Params(_caller, _func, _params, _cb)
          break;
      case 2:
          this._call2Params(_caller, _func, _params, _cb)
          break;
      case 3:
          this._call3Params(_caller, _func, _params, _cb)
          break;
      case 4:
          this._call4Params(_caller, _func, _params, _cb)
          break;
      case 5:
          this._call5Params(_caller, _func, _params, _cb)
          break;
      case 6:
          this._call6Params(_caller, _func, _params, _cb)
          break;
      default:
          this._call(_caller, _func, _cb )
    }   
}
```

....where _caller is the callee, _func is the ethereum contract method call, _params is an array of parameteres to that method call, and _cb is the callee's callback function (where I can set react's state with results etc.). Anyway, I can call this stuff like this:

```
let params = [this.props.ipfsHash, this.objectData.category, this.objectData.format]
this.props.web3.callParamHandler(this, this.premisObject.setObject, params, this._setObject)
```

...and so on. I've got it down as 'a bit of a hack'. Unfortunately, I don't know javascript well enough to do something more elegant - perhaps the spread operator could help, somehow? Anyway, that works for now....